# Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc

Tags: xcode, admob, xcode10, core-telephony

I have upgraded to `Xcode 10` on `High Sierra` and now the [Rewarded Ad example project](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/RewardedVideoExample) from AdMob complains that `com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc` is not working correctly.

Is there a new entitlement that I have to enable? I am searching for hours without any clue.

**UPDATE:**
This only happens from the simulator. On the device it works fine. They must have added a new restriction.

```
2018-09-22 10:59:39.730813+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26168] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2018-09-22 10:59:40.031746+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26281] Failed to create remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.031865+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26261] Failed to ping server after delegate was set
2018-09-22 10:59:40.031938+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.032054+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.032353+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.032451+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.035631+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.035714+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26262] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-09-22 10:59:40.259658+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26314] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process RewardedVideoExample
2018-09-22 10:59:40.259805+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26314] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2018-09-22 10:59:40.259876+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26314] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2018-09-22 10:59:41.020170+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26282] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
Reward based video ad failed to load: No ad returned from any ad server.
2018-09-22 11:00:09.288227+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26168] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/houmie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3FF81C00-0DA2-4F98-8964-A84F14FB14A6/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-09-22 11:00:09.289859+0100 RewardedVideoExample[1449:26168] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I got the same problem with AWS Cognito, did you solve the problem?

Comment: I had to update OS to Mojawe for it to go away.

Comment: Oh ok, in my case I realized that this error was happening only with the simulator but not with a real device. EDIT: I just saw your edit about the simulator thing

Comment: Yes, it's annoying as you have to use your device for testing and can't use the simulator anymore.

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: I no longer have High Sierra to test this. I accept your answer in good faith. :) Thanks

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Running this in Terminal made it go away:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

Comment: It simply sets a config for the simulator to have no ("off") logging for the subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony. It's much better than rejecting all OS messages as some of them (I think auto layout warnings also belongs to it) are really useful

Comment: I receive "unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH"

Comment: @ChikabuZ did you install the command line utilities? If not, let me know if it helped. If you already did, let me know as well.

Comment: @DepartamentoB I installed "Command Line Tools for Xcode" but I receive the same error.

Comment: @ChikabuZ you need to set the location of command line tools in Xcode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108172/xcrun-unable-to-find-simctl

Comment: This is like spraying febreeze on a piss stain. It's still there. Just smell nicer.

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue on Xcode 11+. How Apple devs don't get annoyed with this themselves enough to fix it is beyond me.

Comment: Is there a way to turn it back on? "level:on" is an invalid mode

Answer (score 18):

Well it's working on both the simulator and device in Xcode 10.2.

1. Add CoreTelephony.framework (Optional)
2. Executing the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off" --subsystem 
   com.apple.CoreTelephony
   ```
3. From the Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

   On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`
4. Restart simulator

Comment: for me OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable worked. Xcode 10.3, Mojave

Comment: No it does not work, it does not show debug messages. So layout errors does not appear, either. so sad.

Comment: Just the simctl booted log config command was enough for me.  Turning off OS_ACTIVITY_MODE will hide these along with everything else (including NSLogs) which hides too much.

Comment: Worked for me! (just running xcrun in the terminal was not enough)

Answer (score 8):

I found a workaround restarting the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are experiencing this issue in real devices, linking CoreTelephony.framework to the project fixes the problem.

It does not fix it for the simulator, though.

Answer (score 7):

Run this in Terminal,

- to disappear those log messages

  ```
    xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off" --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
  ```
- to appear those log messages:

  ```
    xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:default"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
  ```

Possible mode levels: off, debug, info, default

**Additional informations:**

It's possible to set the level for "com.apple.CoreTelephony" subsystem on the system level with:

```
sudo log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

Silencing those logs with the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE flag will silence other system logs.

```
From the Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

Answer (score 3):

For people facing this issue when building on real devices, turning on the wifi on the device fixed the problem. This seems to trigger when cellular is being used in stead of wifi.

Comment: for me this happens when i have to debug a scenario when the user is frequently changing connection from WiFi to 4G and vice versa, is there any other way to overcome that ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem in iOS 16 using Xcode 15. The issue for me was that CoreTelephony was being used by one of the pods in my project (Salesforce SDKCore), and the minimum deployment targets in my individual pods did not match what was in my Podfile.

Once the OS versions were in agreement for all frameworks, the CoreTelephony warnings magically disappeared. [Picture example here: To change the deployment target of a Pod, go to Pods project (blue app icon) -> select a pod -> General or Build Settings -> Minimum Deployments or iOS Deployment Target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWreu.png)

Answer (score -4):

I was having the same issue, and this is how I solved it:
Go to the tab **Build Phases** and search for **Bundle React Native code and images** and below **shell** input add:

**export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh**

This worked for me with Xcode 11.3.1

Hope this helps someone!