# Xcode10 run the simulator warning failure to start

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Console error:

> Failed to create remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

Failed to ping server after delegate was set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exactly same error. Seems to be related to Xcode10. When I downgraded to Xcode9.4.1 (which I downloaded from here: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.4.1/Xcode_9.4.1.xip) the error disappeared. I think we have to wait until apple fixed the problem in XCode10.