# App crashes on xamarin ios version when I try to insert the list into SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Xamarin iOS app crashes when trying to insert into the SQLite database after reading data from an API endpoint, it reports this error:

> Remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.

I have checked the size of the data coming from the API and its only 544kb.
I am able to display the data to the screen with only updating the database but I need them to insert into the database so that I can allow the user to search the items from the SQLite database.
If I uninstall the app and run it again, it works fine until I put it in the background and bring it back, then it crashes.

```cs
//Deserializing the data from the API and storing them into a list 
IEnumerable<Member> members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Member>>(json);
//this line below crashes the app
await Db.InsertAllAsync(members);
//the update works very well
await store.UpdateItemsAsync(members);

membersStore = store;
```

the app reports this error on iOS both on simulator and an iPhone

> 2019-04-11 10:29:05.797858-0300 CHA.iOS[8019:113508] [Client] Remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
>   2019-04-11 10:29:05.798118-0300 CHA.iOS[8019:113434] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
>   2019-04-11 10:29:05.798321-0300 CHA.iOS[8019:113515] [Client] Sending selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSD
>   ebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
>   Unhandled Exception:

Comment: try putting  a try/catch around the suspect code and see what exception it is throwing.

Comment: I did that but try n catch does not catch the error, it just jumps to the main.cs where the app crashes but it I get "index was out of range must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" when I put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/52455652/1107580

Comment: it looks like for the simulator, running this will fix it

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony`

Comment: What OS version and Xcode version are you running?

Comment: @IainSmith running the command you gave solve the com.apple.commcenter.coretelphony.xpc error, now  I am getting this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" in the try n catch block on the await Db.InsertAllAsync(members); line of code. I am running iOS 12.2 and Xcode 10.2

Comment: What is the object `members` once it has deserialized? Empty?

Comment: @IainSmith  It is not empty, its a list containing JSON objects that have been deserialized into a readable format.

Comment: await Db.InsertAllAsync(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Member>>(json)).ContinueWith(async t =>
                                await store.UpdateItemsAsync(Db.QueryAsync<Member>("SELECT * FROM Member GROUP BY DisplayName").Result);....This is same code works on android, but will crash the app on ios, so I am trying to implement similar thing using a if statements that targets only ios device