# Xcode 11.1 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have upgraded to **Xcode 11.1** on Mojave and now the [Rewarded Ad example project](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/rewarded-video/) from FacebookSDK complains that com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc is not working correctly.

**PodFile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'testapps' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testapps

  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

end
```

**Usage**

```swift
import UIKit
import FBAudienceNetwork

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBRewardedVideoAdDelegate {

    var rewardedVideoAd : FBRewardedVideoAd!
    var rewardVideoid : String! = "12345678_12345678"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadRewardedVideoAd()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }  

    func loadRewardedVideoAd(){
        self.rewardedVideoAd = FBRewardedVideoAd(placementID: rewardVideoid)
        self.rewardedVideoAd.delegate = self
        self.rewardedVideoAd.load()

    }

    func showRewardedVideoAd(){
        if (self.rewardedVideoAd != nil) && self.rewardedVideoAd.isAdValid {
            self.rewardedVideoAd.show(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonclick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showRewardedVideoAd()
    }


}
```

**AppDelegate**

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBAdSettings.addTestDevice(FBAdSettings.testDeviceHash())
        return true
    }
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let appId: String = "12345678"
        if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" {
            return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        }
        return false
    }
   ...
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
2019-11-22 14:22:12.043889+0900 testapps[12788:336635] <Warning>: You haven't set a value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
2019-11-22 14:22:12.152873+0900 testapps[12788:336635] FBSDKLog: Unable to find a valid UIWindow
2019-11-22 14:22:12.584222+0900 testapps[12788:336777] [logging] table tokens already exists in "CREATE TABLE tokens(                                                  tokenId TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,                                                  token TEXT                                              );"
2019-11-22 14:22:12.584479+0900 testapps[12788:336777] [logging] table events already exists in "CREATE TABLE events(                                                 eventId TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,                                                 tokenId TEXT REFERENCES tokens ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,                                                 priority BIGINT,                                                 type TEXT,                                                 time DOUBLE,                                                 sessionId TEXT,                                                 sessionStartTime DOUBLE,                                                 data TEXT,                                                 attempt BIGINT                                             );"
2019-11-22 14:22:12.606060+0900 testapps[12788:336635] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000332480> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2019-11-22 14:22:14.348231+0900 testapps[12788:336635] [ProcessSuspension] 0x115da8240 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2019-11-22 14:22:14.352725+0900 testapps[12788:336635] [ProcessSuspension] 0x115da82a0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
Video ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
2019-11-22 14:22:21.641634+0900 testapps[12788:336970] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.641691+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.641869+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.643246+0900 testapps[12788:336970] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.643339+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.644317+0900 testapps[12788:336970] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescriptio2019-11-22 14:22:21.644513+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
n=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.693243+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:21.695674+0900 testapps[12788:336965] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2019-11-22 14:22:28.394554+0900 testapps[12788:336635] [ProcessSuspension] 0x115d733f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2019-11-22 14:22:28.481385+0900 testapps[12788:336635] [ProcessSuspension] 0x115d73450 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
Rewarded Video ad video complete - this is called after a full video view, before the ad end card is shown. You can use this event to initialize your reward
2019-11-22 14:22:44.211893+0900 testapps[12788:336635] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2019-11-22 14:22:44.212632+0900 testapps[12788:336635] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
2019-11-22 14:22:58.041772+0900 testapps[12788:336635] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2019-11-22 14:22:58.049248+0900 testapps[12788:336635] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Where is the wrong part of the usage? How can you solve this problem?

Comment: I am getting same issue when add FBAudienceNetwork.framework in my project.hoe to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc)

Answer (score 8):

**Silencing iOS simulator log noise**

This lead to a plethora of stackoverflow questions recommending you disable os_log entirely by setting OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable in your target's scheme. This is fine for some cases but might also silence some actually useful logs, or your own logs if you want to use os_log for its feature-set.

for more info checkout [this](https://www.smileykeith.com/2021/11/16/simulator-log-spew/) also this [like](https://www.iosdev.recipes/simulator/os_log/) should be useful

try running this command

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

to enable it you can run

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level: debug" --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

OR

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level: info" --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

Comment: Can you add a description for this solution. What is this command going to do? This is not a valid response with just a line of code in it. Thanks

Comment: This does not solve the problem just hide the logs.

Comment: @Same7Farouk how do I activate the logs back?

Comment: @Starsky, Thank you for you feedback,  I have updated the answer I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale, please check updated answer I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I added Admob to my react native app.

Add `GADIsAdManagerApp` with boolean key and value should be true in your Info.plist file.

Comment: didn't fix the issue

Comment: @ykonda You did not need to give -point so The solution which i posted worked for me. It may help someone who forget "GADIsAdManagerApp" key their info.plist