# How can i go .xib ViewController to storyboard ViewController and again storyboard to .xib ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my first .xib ViewController how can I go this ViewController to storyboard ViewController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




}
```

Here is storyboard secondViewController and I would like to go again this ViewController to .xib ViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




}
```

Comment: Couldn't understand what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From .xib to .storyboard:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "the-name-of-the-storyboard", bundle: nil)
let ctrl = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerIdentifier")
self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Keep in mind that `SecondViewControllerIdentifier` is the identifier of the storyboard scene; it is not the *class name* of your controller

From .storyboard to .xib:

```
let ctrl = FirstViewController()
self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Assuming that either `FirstViewController.xib` or `First.xib` exists

Comment: I have tried but not working it's showing Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, can you help me?

Comment: But where does it crash? Please debug.

Comment: 2020-02-18 21:01:55.858108+0600 pensacolabeach-dev[23632:424723] [Client] Remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

Comment: That seems to be a problem _within_ your view controller and does not seem to be related to the initial problem. Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc

Comment: Thanks i use this now is working let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "the-name-of-the-storyboard", bundle: nil)
let ctrl = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerIdentifier")
self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I think you forgot to add sb object, Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, just a copy/paste issue :-)