# Lost connection to the debugger on "iPhone" Launching App Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.3

[image]

I've been experiencing this issue a lot with Xcode 11.3.1 when launching the App on the simulator, sometimes just restarting Xcode works, sometimes I have to restart my computer in order to make the app run again. It never happened on Xcode 11.1 tho.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug with the debugger. Try turn off the ”debugger” and run again

Comment: Does this happen even if the iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator window is already open? Does it happen if you try a different simulated device?

Comment: Yes, this happens mostly when I re-run the app, it happens with all the other simulators too.

Comment: I have the same issue. Found that quitting the simulator also helps, but only sometimes. Doing "Erase all contents and settings..." always helps, but this is not the solution of course.

Comment: What I've seen so far is that if I add a simple change to the code, the compilation/run succeeds. So a temporary fix for me is to add a // at the end of any line.

Comment: Same issue pops-uped un in Xcode version 12.2 (12B45b). I am loosing the iPhone connection 4-5 times in last hour or so. Restarted both iPhone and MBP but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on MacOS BigSur and tried using Xcode 12.5 and Xcode 12.4 - the funny thing is when i run a sample app the debugger works. Does anyone know what sort of debugger/simulator settings exist that I can maybe look into? Anything helps!!!

Comment: @gflo Same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @yasinkbas unfortunately no, Ive been running on my device for the meantime but a colleague is experiencing the same issue on device AND simulator... What are your current settings? Maybe we can see some trend

Comment: Did you guys find any solution. We are experiencing same issue with Big Sur 11.3.1 and Xcode 12.3

Comment: It seems macOS has a bug on `11.3<`, I will try to downgrade my version. Also my colleagues have the problem who upgrade their macOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that on the simulator i got an error regarding "com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc". So the fix was to run this in terminal:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

The downside is that you lose the auto layout warnings.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54692253/4041884