# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 in my debug area

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Can anyone please explain to me what this error is and how I can fixed it. I am using Xcode 12.4 and everytime I run my app in my debug area this error always arises. Any help will be much appreciated!!!

````
2021-02-14 12:42:28.811980+1100 Line Up[18396:480644] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-02-14 12:42:28.812210+1100 Line Up[18396:480634] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-02-14 12:42:28.814961+1100 Line Up[18396:480644] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-02-14 12:42:28.815019+1100 Line Up[18396:480634] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-02-14 12:42:28.817765+1100 Line Up[18396:480634] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-02-14 12:42:28.817814+1100 Line Up[18396:480644] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc)

Answer (score 17):

Running this in Terminal :

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

see the
[Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc)

Comment: Still showing Black Screen

Answer (score 2):

For me this error appeared when I forgot to switch on wifi on my test iphone. Maybe this still helps someone.