# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099, com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

My app says it has built successfully but shows the error "No bundle URL Present" with the following in the log:

```
[Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 
"The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc 
was invalidated from this process." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to 
service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc 
was invalidated from this process.}
```

Using Xcode 13, and React Native 65.1 on and iOS 15 Iphone 12.

Can anyone help?

Error log in full

```
2021-10-02 15:22:54.660199+0100 myracnative[556:74795] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2021-10-02 15:22:54.860373+0100 myracnative[556:74799] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
2021-10-02 15:22:54.871831+0100 myracnative[556:74776] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-10-02 15:22:54.876680+0100 myracnative[556:74776] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-10-02 15:22:54.877869+0100 myracnative[556:74776] Connection 2: encountered error(1:61)
2021-10-02 15:22:54.879782+0100 myracnative[556:74776] Task <135B0C12-BD4A-4CF4-8C25-81BCFCE70828>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2021-10-02 15:22:54.886866+0100 myracnative[556:74799] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 90 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc 
was invalidated from this process.}
2021-10-02 15:22:54.889475+0100 myracnative[556:74776] Task <135B0C12-BD4A-4CF4-8C25-81BCFCE70828>.<1> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x282e36a30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <135B0C12-BD4A-4CF4-8C25-81BCFCE70828>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 seems to break com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455652/xcode-10-seems-to-break-com-apple-commcenter-coretelephony-xpc)