# InMobi integration sdk issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, inmobi

I am integrating InMobi ads into my app. I have followed the steps from https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/sdk-documentation/ios-guidelines/overview-ios-guidelines

While I am trying to load any Ads(Banner/Intersterial/Native), I am getting error like this

```
[Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
```

I have tried with the sample that is provided by the team from here https://github.com/InMobi/sdk-sample-code-ios

I have replaced the accountID's and Placement Id's

```
var banner: IMBanner?
banner = IMBanner(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:400, width:320, height:50),
                          placementId: INMOBI_BANNER_PLACEMENT);
banner!.delegate = self;
banner!.load()
self.view.addSubview(self.banner!);

/*
* Code to integrate an InMobi banner via Interface Builder
*/
        
bannerIB?.placementId = INMOBI_BANNER_PLACEMENT;
bannerIB?.load();
```

Can someone tell me how can we fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183203/6783598

Comment: Thank You @BenRockey for that, the error is gone but still the ads are not getting loaded